# CFA model with intentional cross-loadings does not converge in lavaan

Tags: r, r-lavaan, factor-analysis, structural-equation-model

I’m trying to run a confirmatory factor analysis in lavaan on a questionnaire scale of Social Dominance Orientation (SDO), replicating past research done in the development of the scale. However, the model doesn’t converge, and I don’t know why. It gives me the following error:

```
Warning message:
In lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable,  :
  lavaan WARNING: the optimizer warns that a solution has NOT been found!
> 
> summary(fit_SDO, standardized=T,fit.measures=F,rsq=T)
lavaan 0.6-5 did NOT end normally after 3065 iterations
** WARNING ** Estimates below are most likely unreliable
```

The model I’m trying to fit has four factors. First two are dominance and antiegalitarianism, and in addition, the items on these subscales should have a secondary loading on either a pro-trait factor (items originally presented as higher value = higher SDO), or con-trait factor (items originally presented as higher value = lower SDO). I attached an image that shows how the model should look like:

[The model I'm trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzYvK.png)

Below is my model in R. Note that the items in dominance and antiegalitarianism should also load on the pro or con -factors:

```
model_SDO <- '

Dominance =~ SDO7_1 + SDO7_2 + SDO7_3 + SDO7_4 +SDO7_5 + SDO7_6 + SDO7_7 + SDO7_8
AntiEgalitarianism =~ SDO7_9 + SDO7_10 + SDO7_11 + SDO7_12 + SDO7_13 + SDO7_14 + SDO7_15 + SDO7_16

Pro =~ SDO7_1 + SDO7_2 + SDO7_3 + SDO7_4 +SDO7_9 + SDO7_10 + SDO7_11 + SDO7_12
Con =~ SDO7_5 + SDO7_6 + SDO7_7 + SDO7_8 + SDO7_13 + SDO7_14 + SDO7_15 + SDO7_16

'
fit_SDO <- cfa(model_SDO, data = data_all)
summary(fit_SDO, standardized=T,fit.measures=F,rsq=T)
```

Any idea where the problem lies? Is there some other way I should write the model to get it converge and still get the factor structure presented in the image I attached?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I actually managed to solve the problem myself: when I constrain the covariances between the content factors (Dominance and AntiEgalitarianism) and the response-key factors (Pro and Con) to be zero (as the content and the keying shouldn't be correlated), the model runs fine.

```
model_SDO <- '

Dominance =~ SDO7_1 + SDO7_2 + SDO7_3 + SDO7_4 +SDO7_5 + SDO7_6 + SDO7_7 + SDO7_8
AntiEgalitarianism =~ SDO7_9 + SDO7_10 + SDO7_11 + SDO7_12 + SDO7_13 + SDO7_14 + SDO7_15 + SDO7_16

Pro =~ SDO7_1 + SDO7_2 + SDO7_3 + SDO7_4 +SDO7_9 + SDO7_10 + SDO7_11 + SDO7_12
Con =~ SDO7_5 + SDO7_6 + SDO7_7 + SDO7_8 + SDO7_13 + SDO7_14 + SDO7_15 + SDO7_16

Pro ~~ 0*Dominance
Pro ~~ 0*AntiEgalitarianism

Con ~~ 0*Dominance
Con ~~ 0*AntiEgalitarianism
'
```